# Cannot get object DateTimeField gte issue

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have an object

```
class Promo( models.Model ):
    name        = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name"))
    promo_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Promo Name", max_length=255, null=True, default='')

    status  = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=(
        ('publish', 'Published'),
        ('draft',  'Drafted')
    ), default='publish',)

    start_date  = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, auto_now=False, null=True, )
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, auto_now=False, null=True, )
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name, )
```

My settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE   = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE       = "Asia/Jakarta"
USE_I18N        = True
USE_L10N        = True
USE_TZ          = True
```

One of the object value is:
[image: Timezone is 'Asia/Jakarta']

When i filter only the status, it has no problem, but when i want to "get the Promo that have start_date greater than current_datetime, i keep failing, i don't know why, i tried to make the datetime into UTC format since Django seems to return the start_date as UTC timezone. But still fail.

My code:

```
    import pytz
    from django.utils import timezone


    the_promo   = Promo.objects.all().filter(status='publish').first()

    # test
    start_date = the_promo.start_date
    start_date_utc                      = start_date
    current_datetime_date_in_asia_jakarta = timezone.localtime(start_date_utc)
    current_datetime                    = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Jakarta')
    current_datetime_utc                = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('UTC'))

    if current_datetime_utc > start_date_utc:
        b='bigger!'
    else:
        b='not bigger'

    the_promo_to_be_used2    = Promo.objects.all().filter(start_date__gte=current_datetime_utc, status='publish').first()
```

Example values from debug:

```
start_date = 2017-11-17 06:17:49+00:00
start_date_utc = 2017-11-17 06:17:49+00:00
current_datetime = 2017-11-17 13:49:13.212000+07:00
current_datetime_utc = 2017-11-17 06:49:13.212000+00:00
b = 'bigger!' # this works how come the query does not work?
```

but the_promo_to_be_used2 keeps getting None

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Exception? Wrong results?

Comment: what i am trying to do is "get the Promo that has start_date bigger than current_datetime, but also expire_date less than current_datetime

Comment: aleosd, i keep getting None , i was hoping to get that object since my datetime is bigger than "2017-11-11 13:17:49"

Comment: i edited the question to give more info

Comment: Your "get the Promo that has start_date bigger than current_datetime, but also expire_date less than current_datetime"
will give you nothing. say:
start_date = 17-Dec-2017
exp_date = 10-Nov-2017
curr_date = 17 Nov- 2017

what you actually want to do @RaymondSeger

Comment: I want to get Promo that already started, so start_date should be LESS THAN instead of greater than. Ankush.

Comment: I guess, Promo that already started, and not expired yet must be your requirement then. Is it so?

Comment: yes, that is correct, Ankush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date = datetime.datetime(2017,11,17,06,17)
>>> current_date = datetime.datetime(2017,11,17,13,49)
>>> start_date >= current_date  # start_date__gte=current_date
False
```

Check your filters, change `_gte` to `_lt` according to desired logic. From what I see now, `start_date` is less then `current date`, so filter expression is working well, you just doing wrong filtering.

Comment: this is so humiliating, you're right. I want to get Promo that already started, so start_date should be LESS THAN instead of greater than.

Answer (score 1):

your can simply apply filter() on model. No need to use all().filter().
Also, It work for me:

`Promo.objects.filter(status='publish', start_date__gte=curr_date).first()`

where curr_date is  the datetime object contains today's date.

i.e curr_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 0, 0)

including exp_date into filter query and as per your latest comment.it will be:

`Promo.objects.filter(status='publish', start_date__lte=curr_date, expiry_date__gte=curr_date).first()`